# PcapDotNet получение списка сетевых интерфейсов

Tags: c#, сеть, pcap

Пишу генератор пакетов. Пытаюсь следующим образом получить список сетевых интерфейсов на устройстве:

```
    public string[] GetNetworkLocalDevices()
    {
        string[] Interfaces = new string[LocalDeviceList.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < LocalDeviceList.Count; i++)
        {
            Interfaces[i] = LocalDeviceList[i].Description;
        }
        return Interfaces;
    }
```

В итоге получаю следующий результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако Wireshark выдает немного другие результаты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал вместо свойства Description выбирать Name, получил совсем не то, что хотел:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В принципе не понимаю, что можно было сделать не так, возможен ли вариант, что это как-то связано с основным языком ОС? И как получить адекватные результаты из pcap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, вы сравниваете теплое с мягким: на первом скриншоте названия сетевых адаптеров, а на втором - подключений. Связать между собой имя адаптера, имя подключения и его GUID можно с помощью System.Net.NetworkInformation

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            var ifs = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

            foreach (var interf in ifs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Network name: "+interf.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Adapter name: "+interf.Description);
                Console.WriteLine("Adapter GUID: " + interf.Id);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```